# How to configure transfers for different accounts in stripe with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-10

I am working on a platform where I want to charge a commission myself. This is my current code:

```
class StripePayment
{
    private ?Authenticatable $user;

    public function __construct(
        private readonly Stripe $stripe,
        private StripeClient    $stripeClient,
        private readonly Charge $charge,
        private readonly Transfer $transfer
    )
    {
        $this->user = auth()->user();
        $this->stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $this->stripeClient = new StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    }

    public function charge(array $prices, string $paymentToken)
    {
        $stripeResponse = $this->createOrUpdateCustomer($paymentToken);

        $payment = $this->charge::create([
            'amount' => $prices['clubPrice'] * 100,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'customer' => $stripeResponse->id,
            'description' => __('Reservation created')
        ]);

        $clubTransfer = $this->transfer::create([
            'amount' => $prices['clubPrice'] * 100,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'destination' => 'default_for_currency',
            'transfer_group' => $payment->id,
        ]);
        
        $yourTransfer = $this->transfer::create([
            'amount' => $prices['ourPrice'] * 100,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'destination' => 'default_for_currency',
            'transfer_group' => $payment->id,
        ]);

        dd($clubTransfer);
    }

    public function createOrUpdateCustomer(string $token)
    {
        if ($this->user->stripe_id) {
            $stripeResponse = $this->stripeClient->customers->update(
                $this->user->stripe_id,
                [
                    'name' => $this->user->name,
                    'email' => $this->user->email,
                    'source' => $token,
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $stripeResponse = $this->stripeClient->customers->create([
                'name' => $this->user->name,
                'email' => $this->user->email,
                'source' => $token,
            ]);

            $this->user->stripe_id = $stripeResponse->id;
            $this->user->save();
        }

        return $stripeResponse;
    }
}
```

In $prices array, I have this:

```
array:2 [ // app/Services/StripePayment.php:29
  "clubPrice" => 9.2
  "ourPrice" => 0.8
]
```

What I want to do is charge "ourPrice" to my bank account and "clubPrice" to another bank account. How could I achieve this? For now in development mode

I try this but without results

```
    $stripeResponse = $this->createOrUpdateCustomer($paymentToken);
    
    $payment = $this->charge::create([
        'amount' => $prices['clubPrice'] * 100,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'customer' => $stripeResponse->id,
        'description' => __('Reservation created')
    ]);

    $clubTransfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
        'amount' => $prices['clubPrice'] * 100,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'destination' => 'acct_1234567890',
        'transfer_group' => $payment->id,
    ]);
    
    // Realizar la transferencia a tu cuenta
    $yourTransfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
        'amount' => $prices['ourPrice'] * 100,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'destination' => 'acct_0987654321',
        'transfer_group' => $payment->id,
    ]);
```

Comment: what is the issue ? If it's `insufficient_funds`, use your Charge ID as `source_transaction` : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers#transfer-availability

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use what Stripe calls "[Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers)", but you're using the Charges API which is legacy and doesn't support all the same functionality as easily. I would recommend upgrading to Payment Intents and using Stripe's new product

If you must use the legacy Charges API, it's possible that you might be trying to transfer more than you have available after the successful charge, since it looks like you might be creating a charge for whatever `prices['clubPrice'] * 100` is, then x2 subsequent transfers to 2 different Connect accounts afterward.

Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? When you say "I try this but without results", what do you mean?